# Bootstrap for nonlinear regression (quasibinomial GLM) using `marginaleffects::inferences` after matching

Tags: r, bootstrap, matching, marginal-effect

### Background

Looking into the [MatchIt articles](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/estimating-effects.html#estimating-standard-errors-and-confidence-intervals) made me realize that using Bootstrap with BCa is a better practice for assessing uncertainty estimation (since: *"For nonlinear models (e.g., logistic regression), the delta method is only an approximation subject to error"*). Using [Estimating Effects After Matching](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/estimating-effects.html#the-cluster-bootstrap) article for clustered bootstrap, I got satisfactory results. Still, I would like to utilize the full functionality of the `marginaleffects` package, for instance - using the "by =" to get stratified results, etc.

The `marginaleffects` [documentation](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/bootstrap.html#boot) shows how can `marginaleffects::avg_comparisons` can be used in combination with the `boot` package using `marginaleffect::inferences`.

### The problem

When I try to use bootstrap after running `marginaleffects::avg_comparisons` with clusters G-comp according to `MatchIt` article, I get this error:

```
avg_comparisons(fit,
                variables = "A",
                vcov = ~subclass,
                newdata = subset(md, A == "1"),
                wts = "weights",
                comparison = "lnratioavg",
                transform = exp
) %>%
  inferences(method = "boot", R = 999, conf_type = "bca")

# Error: Assertion failed. One of the following must apply:
#   * checkmate::check_choice(x): Must be element of set {'exp','ln'}, but is not atomic scalar
# * checkmate::check_function(x): Must be a function, not 'list'
```

Also, running the code after removing the `transform = exp` or/and
`comparison = "lnratioavg"` arguments shows results that are very different than the estimate and CI computed using delta method or bootstrapping after manually computing G-comp. as shown in the article above (which are very similar in my instance).

##### To avoid from posting very long code, I'm attaching a [reproduced example with downloadable code](http://rpubs.com/arielhasidim/1059139)

### My questions:

1. Is using `marginaleffects` with `boot` considered good practice in a matched cohort, and is it an appropriate and equal substation for the manual g-computation in the MatchIt articles?
2. What is the proper code for doing it?
3. How to run bootstrap with `by =` argument, and is this a good practice?

================

#### UPDATE - the reproduced example above has been updated with @Noah's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supplying `vcov = ~subclass` does not tell `inferences()` that you want clustering; it tells `avg_comparisons()` that you want to use a cluster-robust delta method-based standard error, which you don't want. You want the cluster bootstrap, in which clusters (matched pairs or strata) are resampled in each bootstrap sample.

`marginaleffects` does not support the cluster bootstrap when using `inferences()` with `method = "boot"` or `method = "rsample"` because the arguments passed to `inferences()` are passed directly to the corresponding bootstrapping functions in those packages, which also do not support the cluster bootstrap by default. `method = "fwb"` does support the cluster bootstrap through its `cluster` argument, but that uses the fractional weighted bootstrap, which has not been investigated in this scenario and isn't guaranteed to work well with weighted regression models supplied to `avg_comparisons()` (for example, the `wts` argument can't be used).

So, your options are the following:

- Petition the `boot` or `rsample` authors to allow the cluster bootstrap to be used by supplying an argument to the corresponding function. This will likely not go well if these packages were not designed with this in mind.
- Investigate whether `fwb` will work for your purposes by doing a manual assessment outside of `inferences()`. That is, make sure the fractional weighted cluster bootstrap produces results that are valid for use after matching, since this has not been investigated.
- Manually code the cluster bootstrap as explained in the `MatchIt` vignette. Instead of computing all the quantities internally manually, you can instead just call `avg_comparisons()` within each bootstrap iteration and extract the effect estimates to be used in computing the confidence intervals. Remember to set `vcov = FALSE` in the call to `avg_comparisons()` since you will only be extracting the effect estimates, not the standard errors. This will run much more slowly than coding it yourself, but gives you full access to the infrastructure of `avg_comparisons()` up to the point the effects are estimated. An example demonstrating how to do this is in the `WeightIt` [documentation](https://ngreifer.github.io/WeightIt/articles/estimating-effects.html#using-bootstrapping-to-estimate-confidence-intervals).

Good on you for taking the time to figure out the best method instead of taking he easy way out and just using the cluster-robust SE.

---

Here is some example code, building on the liked file in the OP.

```r
#Unique pair IDs
pair_ids <- levels(md$subclass)

#Unit IDs, split by pair membership
split_inds <- split(seq_len(nrow(md)), md$subclass)

cluster_boot_fun <- function(pairs, i) {
  
  #Extract units corresponding to selected pairs
  ids <- unlist(split_inds[pairs[i]])
  
  #Subset md with block bootstrapped indices
  boot_md <- md[ids,]
  
  #Fit outcome model
  fit <- glm(Y_B ~ A * (X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + 
                          X6 + X7 + X8 + X9),
             data = boot_md, weights = weights,
             family = quasibinomial())
  
  ## G-computation ##
  est <- avg_comparisons(fit,
                         variables = "A",
                         vcov = FALSE,
                         newdata = subset(boot_md, A == "1"),
                         wts = "weights",
                         comparison = "ratioavg",
                         by = "X_ORDINAL")
  setNames(est$estimate, paste(est$contrast, est$X_ORDINAL, sep = "|"))
}

cluster_boot_out <- boot(pair_ids, cluster_boot_fun,
                         R = R)
cluster_boot_out
```

Comment: I used the last option, and the Rmarkdown page is now updated with the solution. Also, I used the `newdata` argument in the `marginaleffects::avg_comparisons` function to manually run a stratified bootstrap. A comparison to with calculation using the delta method looks promising. Can you please approve this approach for stratifying? I must say, I admire your work and comprehensive answers, thank you!

Comment: Your code is not correct; I'll provide an example in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, the code in the Rmarkdown is updated accordingly.

Comment: Followup problem: In rare instances, we get a bootstrap data copy that doesn't contain all `X_ORDINAL` levels. The result is, for example, that the G-comp gives only 3 rows of `est` instead of 4 as a response to the `cluster_boot_fun`, and then the boot function fails with an error (boot::boot line 124: `...t.star[r, ] <- res[[r]]` gives: `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`). Can I avoid this? I already tried to expand the factor beforehand, doesn't help.

Comment: This is a fundamental problem with the basic bootstrap and a reason to use consider an alternative method. I think at this point just using the cluster-robust SE should be fine.