# Can I remove a single bootstrap sample before calculating CI?

Tags: r, bootstrap

I'm using `boot::boot` with BCa to assess uncertainty estimation for a binomial model. The statistic function is manually coded as a cluster bootstrap with G-computation (full explanation and replicable code: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/620201/323174).

In rare instances, I get a sample that contains only some of the cluster levels, which returns an incomplete sample estimate (i.e., a table with a missing row for one of the cluster levels). As a response, the boot function fails with an error (`boot::boot` line 124: `...t.star[r, ] <- res[[r]]` gives: `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`).

To solve this, I edited the `boot::boot` function to remove the incomplete samples and return a smaller bootstrap with an updated R.

For example, this bootstrap:

```
boot_out.rrt.dich.uo <- boot(pair_ids, boot_fun_by,
                         R = 99)
```

Returns this:

```
ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = pair_ids, statistic = boot_fun_by, R = 98)


Bootstrap Statistics :
        original        bias     std. error
t1* 3.494313e-01  2.572816e+11 2.546256e+12
t2* 2.746097e+13 -2.622462e+13 5.558065e+12
t3* 1.415745e-11  4.028178e+03 1.470726e+04
```

Pay attention as the `R = 99` from the function becomes `R = 98` in the result (the actual code changed in the `boot::boot` function can be seen [in this fork](https://github.com/arielhasidim/boot_fix/commit/e951bbde87e7f73dd0c9a2e28caf188fd1ea6e68?diff=split&w=0).)

**Will this offend the calculation of `boot::boot.ci` using `type = "bca"` beyond reducing the number of my samples?**

Comment: I always find it useful to address this problem by asking, "what would I do if this problem occurred *in the actual data?*"  What would you do then?

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the suggestion, and sorry for the intricate scenario! This is actually a follow-up question; the original question dealt with the bigger problem (see the link in the OP). However, I believe the core theoretical question remains relevant: Is it ever permissible to "prune" a few samples before assessing confidence intervals?

Comment: The answer depends on the specifics.  I take the need for pruning as a red flag: it suggests your method to compute CIs is not really appropriate and needs to be reexamined and modified to handle all possible samples, not just the one you actually have.  But as a practical matter, when the frequency of such exceptional cases is so low that it wouldn't affect the CI appreciably, you might *hope* you could ignore them.